# Reformat MongoDB results from aggregate

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I'm coming from SQL world and starting with MongoDB, I'm still a bit confused...
I have a collection with this structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5769b51f675e6190119935ec"),
    "city" : "City1",
    "company" : "Company1",
    "country" : "Country1",
    "zip" : "23345",
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5769b51f675e6190119935ed"),
    "city" : "City1",
    "company" : "Company2",
    "country" : "Country1",
    "zip" : "1245",
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5769b51f675e6190119935ee"),
    "city" : "City2",
    "company" : "Company1",
    "country" : "Country1",
    "zip" : "123445",
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5769b51f675e6190119935ef"),
    "city" : "City1",
    "company" : "Company2",
    "country" : "Country1",
    "zip" : "1235445",
}
```

and my query,

```
db.getCollection('stores').aggregate([{"$group":{"_id" : {city :"$city", company : "$company"}}}])
```

I'm using angular and NodejS+Express to get the data from de database and I get the data with this format

```
[
    {
        _id:{
            city:"City1",
            company:"Compnay1"
        }
    },
    {
        _id:{
            city:"City1",
            company:"Company2"
        }
    },
    {
        _id:{
            city:"City2",
            company:"Compan1"
        }
    }
]
```

So I'm wondering if there's a way to get this query result without the _id key,

like this:

```
 [
        {
            city:"City1",
            company:"Compnay1"
        },
        {
            city:"City1",
            company:"Company2"
        },
        {
            city:"City2",
            company:"Compan1"
        }
 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `$project` as aggregation pipeline operator in the next pipeline stage:

```
db.getCollection('stores').aggregate([
  {"$group":{"_id" : {city :"$city", company : "$company"}}},
  {"$project": {"city": "$_id.city", "company": "$_id.company", "_id": 0}}
])
```